# Nice inset border in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm really loving this border style I've seen around on the tubes lately:

[image]

It'll probably look better if you just view it on the site: http://markdotto.com/bootstrap/

I'm particularly interested in how they're creating this effect, it seems that the bottom border is highlighted while the top is darkened. I know how I'd do this in Photoshop, but how are they doing it in CSS?

```
code, pre {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Konqueror */

  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* FF 3.6+ */

  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* IE10 */

  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */

  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */

  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* Opera 11.10 */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)', endColorstr='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6 & IE7 */

  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)', endColorstr='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', GradientType=0)";
  /* IE8+ */

  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  /* the standard */

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: "Monaco", Courier New, monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
code {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
pre {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

I'm not interested so much in the background as the border. You'll have to visit the site to truly appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand... your question includes the answer! :) What don't you understand about the code you posted?

Comment: oh i think he is asking if you look at the website example. the gradient changes as the background changes color. How does the site go about doing this through out the website without needing to care were the gradient is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually pretty straight forward to accomplish. I've set up a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXpXf/60/) that kind of outlines how the effect is being achieved in this case, explaining the code you posted.

Hope this clears it up! If not, I'd be stoked to elaborate more. I love css and rarely get a chance to use it in my work.

### edit - The answer from the jsfiddle:

The top of the `<pre>` is darkened with an inset black, transparent box-shadow:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
```

rgba() here means *Red, Green, Blue, Alpha*. 0, 0, 0 means black, and .25 means 25% opaque, or 75% transparent.

The bottom of the `<pre>` is lined with a normal, white, single pixel transparent box-shadow:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
```

So the inset black shadow presides inside of the element, giving depth, while the white (255, 255, 255) shadow hangs 1 pixel below the element, giving the illusion of a highlight.

The cool thing is, in this code the two declarations are combined:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
```

#### Here is the css used in the sample, with vendor prefixed declarations removed for brevity:

```
body {
  background: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/debut_dark.png');
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

code {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

pre {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: Menlo, monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
```

It can be applied to a `<pre>` element to see the desired effect. If this doesn't work, you may need to apply vendor prefixes to box-shadow and background-image.

Comment: Yes, I'd really appreciate a little bit of a more thorough walkthrough on how the effect is created. There seems to be a ton of styling going on in the `pre` tag and I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding it. I understand the `box-shadow` stuff now, but I'm having difficulty with the `background-image` and `background-color` styles in there. Genius work though, and thanks for being willing to explain.

Comment: No problem. In this case, `background-image` is producing a transparent gradient to give emphasis the sort of depth we're perceiving. Then our `background-color` is first set to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`, then later to `rgba(0,0,0,0.1)`. I have a feeling this is an accidental redundancy from http://markdotto.com/bootstrap/. I believe it's in place to provide some contrast if the background-image fails.

Comment: Also, the background-image linear gradient is explained really well [here](http://css-tricks.com/5700-css3-gradients/). One thing that will make a lot of this so much more simple: You can ignore all of that -moz/-webkit/-o/etc. These are vendor prefixes; implementations of the css3 spec for us to work with until the final spec is released. Try to look at all of the repetitive code as a single line - Each declaration is doing the same thing really, but under a different prefix. Confusing, annoying, but unfortunately necessary.

Comment: Please add the actual answer here at SO. The jsfiddle link is not guaranteed to be permanent.

Answer (score 4):

The key part of the effect you seem to be talking about—the appearance of the edges, not the gradient in the background as explained by the other answers—is this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
```

There are two shadows being applied there: a standard box shadow (which Photoshop would call a “Drop Shadow”) at the bottom with a lighter color (`rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)`), and an inset one (which Photoshop would call an “Inner Shadow”) at the top with a darker color (`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)`).

Comment: When I take that and apply it to an element, I'm not seeing really too much. See http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/KYw7e/ You're right, I'm looking for that really crisp, nice-looking outline.

Comment: It won't work with a black background, nor with a white foreground. You need the shadows to be darker/brighter than both. See http://jsfiddle.net/SvMQ3/

Comment: @RicardoTomasi It also works best with a gradient background, so that the contrast can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Alright this one was a tricky one. looks like all they did was use a fairly dark clear transparent/alpha effect in a dark to light gradient. so it looks like its changing with the websites wallpaper or background.

You have the code so its pointless to give you an example. So its really a trick to the eye with the background to the website.