# Change the border of td element?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp-classic

Can i change the border of td element exactly like a textbox?
I cannot use a textbox here because of some issues.

### Edit 1

I needed multiselect dropdown.
So i used a `textbox`(for same look and feel like `dropdownlist`) and on click I displayed a `listbox`.
But in this case `selectedindexchanged` for `listbox` was not getting called.
But if I use `label` in td element there instead of a `textbox` `list_selectedindexchanged` gets called.

### Edit 2

I am displaying a listbox after clicking a textbox.
But the listboxselectedindexchanged is not getting called if i select a list item.I have set the autopostback property of listbox to true.
Therefore i couldnot use textbox here.
If listboxselectedindexchanged event gets called called with textbox, then i have no issues with textbox.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "exactly like a textbox". Different browsers render textboxes differently. What are the issues you are referring to? If you need to use a textbox, but have issues, I'd ask a question about those issues instead.

Comment: i needed multiselect dropdown.So i used a textbox(for same look and feel like dropdownlist) and on click i displayed a listbox. But in this case selectedindexchanged for listbox was not getting called. But if I use label in td element there instead of a textbox list_selectedindexchanged gets called.

Comment: check out :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129775/nice-inset-border-in-css3

Comment: Yes obcourse you could edit it in your css. Are you using a td inside a table?

Comment: I am using the textbox now, the issue with event is resolved with some javascript.  @Eamon your link was useful but i didn't need to format td as textbox now.